# What are Walter and Donny's occupations (when the events in the movie are unfolding)?

Tags: character, the-big-lebowski

The only detail I can remember that can give a hint on what [Walter](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0003521/)'s job was in *The Big Lebowski*, is that he works in Security, as written in his van:

[image]

Can't remember anything for [Donny](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0003517/). Is there another hint in the movie on what Donny's job could be and what Walter's job in Security is, specifically?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance to the movie, but what plot significance does their jobs have on said plot?

Comment: @TylerShads It might give background on why those characters behave the way they do and why they are treated the way they are in the movie. It might also give insights on how their jobs could have brought them (including The Dude) together.

Comment: I don't believe any reference to Donny's livelihood being mentioned in the movie

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Walter owns his own security store. He is clearly in front of Sobchak Security store when The Dude picks him up to go pay the ransom.

The fact that he is a Viet Nam vet, is into arms, interrogation, and security is exceedingly important to the movie.

As for Donny's day job, I have no clue. Great question though.

[image]

Comment: what's a "security store" ?

Comment: It's a store that sells security items, such as cameras, recorders, alarms, pepper spray, and other home, business, and personal security items. My guess is that Walter installed security systems that he sold at his store, dude.

Answer (score 5):

During first scene at the bowling alley, Donny is wearing a cleaning company’s jacket:

[image]

This tells me he is a janitor/cleaner

Comment: I believe the nametags on the bowling shirts Donnie wears all have someone else's names on them. I only just heard this and I haven't confirmed it myself.

Comment: Unfortunately, the name on the shirt is *Johnson.* Also, Donny wears several shirts from different companies throughout the film (all with names that are clearly not his own).

Comment: Perhaps this shirt is a reference to the Sopranos where the character played by the same actor does work for a laundry company (briefly)?

Comment: Maybe one of those Richard/Dick shortenings so Johnson -> Johnny -> Donny?

Comment: @LevenTrek Sopranos started in 1999, which was after TBL was released. (And then Buscemi's character doesn't come along until a few season in IIRC)

Answer (score 2):

Having watched the movie a few times, As far as I can tell no where in the movie is Donny's job indirectly or directly expressed (I could be wrong). However we can infer from the plot and overall theme of the movie the following

- They all have places they live which costs money
- They all bowl which costs money
- For the most part they have decent clothes which cost money

Logically they all have to have some sort of income. My guess is they have some sort of slacker time part time jobs along with some sort of other income.

Comment: You realize that the Dude does not have a job?